# How to enable special keys (ctrl-c, ctrl-v, tab, delete) Windows.Form.WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a Window.Form that has a WebBrowser control on it. How do you enable the control to process special keys like the Tab key for navigating between controls?

I've seen answers for doing this in activeX and mfc controls but not for the .NET control.

Thanks

Comment: If someone else is looking for a solution, that helped in my case: [DEL and BACKSPACE keys get eaten from WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246006/6267940)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows.Forms WebBrowser control is a wrapper on the activex control. You have the property `WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled` ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.webbrowsershortcutsenabled.aspx)), however, that should be `true` by default.

Comment: I have that enabled. It seems to have no effect on it.

Comment: Must be something else... I just tested it on a WinForms application I've made, and, at least Tab, and Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V work correctly. Are you maybe previewing the keys on the form where the control is on and cancelling the events? Or maybe the web control is contained on other control which is cancelling the bubbling?

Comment: Flag this as the answer because it is what enables it. My problem turned out to be I showed the dialog container with the control then afterward navigated the control to a page. Showing it after initiating the navigation worked.

Comment: Also the form is a child of another application. So the shortcuts only work if the form is opened as a modal form. The parent application must be consuming the events before the plugin form can receive them.

Comment: working, thanks. I was about to blame Vuejs. I wonder how Del key is considered a shortcut!